# Initial frame of subview with delayed animation not applied until the animation starts

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to solve a problem with some code displaying an informational "toast". The toast view is initialised with a computed frame, and then added as a subview of the main view. An animation is then applied to fade the toast away. If the animation has no delay, the layout is as expected. The fade starts immediately though.
If the animation is delayed, the first instance of the toast behaves as expected: it appears in the correct location, remains solid for 1s and fades over the next second.
If a sequence of toasts are displayed quickly, they will appear at `0, 0`, until the delay expires, at which point the animation begins and the frame updates to the correct location.

```
func showToast(_ message: String) {
  let frame = computeToastFrame()
  let toast = Toast(frame: frame)
  view.addSubView(toast)
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, options: .allowUserInteraction) {
    toast.alpha = 0.02
  } completion: { _ in
    toast.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

I've tried various `.setNeedsLayout()` and `.layoutIfNeeded()` to give the computed frame chance to be applied, but with no success.

**Update**:

I thought that this captured the key aspects of the code, but it doesn't produce the same behaviour:

```
// Start a new iOS app from the standard Xcode template, then
// replace the content of ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var counter = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let button = UIButton(configuration: .bordered())
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showToast), for: .primaryActionTriggered)

        button.setTitle("Toast!", for: .normal)

        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    @objc
    func showToast() {
        let toast = UILabel(frame: .init(x: 10, y: 500, width: 200, height: 100))
        toast.backgroundColor = .blue
        toast.text = "Toast #\(counter)"
        toast.textAlignment = .center
        toast.textColor = .white

        counter += 1

        view.addSubview(toast)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 2) {
            toast.alpha = 0.02
        } completion: { _ in
            toast.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

The misbehaviour I am seeing must be down to a quirk elsewhere in the app. A change that has resolved the issue (and maybe hints at the true cause) is to take the delay responsibility away from `UIView.animate`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0) {
        toast.alpha = 0.02
    } completion: { _ in
        toast.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

The origin of the action is a conventional button tap, passed down a delegate chain to a coordinator that arranges for the toast to be displayed. I don't think there's any not-main-queue potential there, but will check tomorrow...

Comment: Quick test - https://pastebin.com/5xGeibv5 - and I'm not seeing what you are describing. Add enough code so we can see it - review [mre].

Comment: I've attempted, but failed, to reproduce the problem in isolation. Original post updated to reflect that.